# What git branches should I use for two actively developed builds of my app?

Tags: git

not sure how to use git branches to best achieve this working pattern:

- I have an app that I develop in git
- There is a current version, which is still in active development
- There is also a future version in development

The problem is, when I make a change to the current version, such as adding a new feature, I want that to be pulled (pushed?) into the future version. However, when I do something like change the version number of the current version, that shouldn't overwrite the version number of the future version. How do I make one change merge but not the other? That's a simple example, there will be lots of other little things that I don't always want merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One system that I typically use is to create "feature branches" for your work. This way, you can merge your feature branch into both your current branch and the future one and leave versioning information as an implicit commit in those respective branches. The basic idea here is just using a higher level of gradation with your commits/branches.

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout the files to the new branch from the old branch individually. I wrote about this [here](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/510914433/getting-files-from-another-branch).

Another way of doing it. create a new branch off your old version branch, then do an interactive rebase of your new version branch off this copy branch. Remove the commits that you don't want to include in the new version. This means you'll have to make changes that you don't want to take over to the new version in their own commits which can be excluded from the rebase.

You can delete the copy branch when you're done.